# Making Durandal SPA site SEO friendly

Tags: seo, single-page-application, durandal, google-search

I'm trying to make a Single page application crawlable, and has successfully created HTML snapshots on demand, but I'm having difficulty understanding if "#" fragments is considered "pretty URL", or if it's just "#!"?

I've read http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Making-Durandal-Apps-SEO-Crawlable.html and https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification

It seems to me that only "#!" is a pretty URL and that Durandal does not support this. It supports pushState, though. According to the last link, this should **not** be included if the page already are using pretty URLs:

```
<meta name="fragment" content="!">
```

One effect being that the indexed version of the page "www.domain.com?_escaped_fragment_=#" will be "www.domain.com#", and we want the URL without the hashbang to be indexed of course.

So to wrap it up - I will use # fragments, and not #!, should I include the meta fragment or not - and our internal links will also have # fragments, and not #!, will they be followed by Google?

Thanks for input!

**Sitenote**
According to the first link you could actually change the fragment to "#!" instead of just "#", but I cannot get it to work. I tried overloading the convertRouteToHash() function, it goes in, and I don't see a change no matter what the function returns.

Comment: First of all the answer is - there is no good way , a huge downside to durandal.  But what I did is create a sitemap and it contains each url with the hash included in it and this gives the web crawlers  ( or at least google ) the info to know that each hash is actually a different page

Comment: Have you gotten any results yet or do you just hope for it to work? :)

Comment: it works , just checked right now to confirm , right now we have 130 real time active members and below the graph all of the unique url's that are all different hashes are all listed.   Note that I think this may only be for Google

Comment: Good to hear! :) Thank you for checking. Sounds easy enough... Just hoping that Google doesn't change things so you (and I) will lose ranking.

Answer (score 0):

Nowdays URL fragments are obsolete: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification

I now use pushState instead and all pages are indexed just fine.